# What exceptions can be raised by Python HTTPX's json() method?

Tags: python, httpx

The excellent [Python HTTPX package](https://www.python-httpx.org) has a [`.json()`](https://www.python-httpx.org/quickstart/#json-response-content) method for conveniently decoding resposnes that are in JSON format. But the documentation does not mention what exceptions can be raised by `.json()`, and even looking through the code, it is not obvious to me what the possible exceptions might be.

For purposes of writing code like the following,

```
try:
    return response.json()
except EXCEPTION:
    print('This is not the JSON you are looking for')
```

what exceptions should I test for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even looking through the code, it is not obvious to me what the possible exceptions might be.

Here's my attempt at looking through [it](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/2d37321842c566b1fd81f9627ab4072064286d16/httpx/_models.py#L751):

```
def json(self, **kwargs: typing.Any) -> typing.Any:
    if self.charset_encoding is None and self.content and len(self.content) > 3:
        encoding = guess_json_utf(self.content)
        if encoding is not None:
            return jsonlib.loads(self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs)
    return jsonlib.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
```

- `self.content` can raise `ResponseNotRead` if (as it sounds like) the response has not been read yet. However, this is almost certainly due to a logical error in the code rather than any meaningful problem at runtime worth detecting; so there is no good reason to catch this. (It also wouldn't happen with the most straightforward use cases, such as the one shown in the documentation.) Otherwise, `self.content` will be a `bytes`, so `len` will work.
- `self.charset_encoding` will either return `None` (if there is no corresponding data in the response header) or else eventually use the standard library `email.message.Message.get_content_charset` to parse a content type from the response header. The latter is not documented to raise any exceptions; so there should not be any exception from accessing this value.
- `guess_json_utf` will necessarily be passed a `bytes` that is at least 4 bytes long. Nothing in its logic should be able to fail under those conditions. Either `None` or a string will be returned.
- If `jsonlib.loads` is called using `self.content.decode(encoding)`, then `encoding` was necessarily not `None`, and is a valid encoding name returned from `guess_json_utf` However, it's possible that the `self.content` (`bytes` data) is not valid data (i.e., convertible to text using the guessed text encoding). This would cause `UnicodeDecodeError`.
- Otherwise, it's called with `self.text`. If the underlying `_text` was set before, it will be a string and gets returned. If there is no content in the response, an empty string is returned. Otherwise, decoding is attempted using a default text encoder with a `"replace"` error-handling policy. There again shouldn't be anything that could cause the text encoding name to be invalid, so again this can only raise `UnicodeDecodeError`, and even that shouldn't be possible with the `"replace"` error-handling policy.
- Finally: `jsonlib.loads` is simply `json.loads` (i.e., the standard library `json`). if the code gets this far, `json.loads` will definitely be given a string to load; all possible issues with the string contents will be reported as `JSONDecodeError`.

---

tl;dr: the possible exceptions that make sense to catch are `JSONDecodeError` (the response is not valid JSON - this includes e.g. an empty response) and `UnicodeDecodeError` (the response is corrupt in some way, for example it mixes bytes intended to encode text in two different ways, or it's supposed to be UTF-8 but contains bytes that are illegal in that encoding; **or** it's encoded using a non-UTF scheme, such as Latin-1, in a way that is incompatible with the corresponding guessed UTF scheme, *and* doesn't advertise the encoding in the header).